# Dask drop() not dropping columns when I need it to

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm new to Dask and the manner in which columns are dropped is confusing to me. I've read a csv file into the Dask dataframe. Then suppose I have this:

```
print(len(columns_to_drop))   # There are 66
print(len(list(df.columns)))  # The Dask columns before the drop
df.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1).compute(). # Drop the columns
pd_df = df.compute()  #  Create a Pandas dataframe
print(pd_df.shape[1])  # Pandas dataframe columns
print(len(list(df.columns)))  # The Dask columns after the drop
```

What I get from the print statements:

- 66 columns to drop
- 207 Dask df columns before the drop
- 207 Pandas column count
- 207 Dask column after the drop

Comment: Add `inplace=True` to `.drop()`

Comment: fwiw, the dask syntax matches pandas here. [`pd.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) is also not inplace by default.

Comment: Michael, Dask doesn't support "inplace"

`TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the dataframe fits into memory, this should do the trick:

```py
df = df.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1) # Drop the columns
pd_df = df.compute()  #  Create a Pandas dataframe
```

Comment: That was the behavior I expected Sultan. But not happening.

`ddf = dd.read_csv(clean_csv_filepath, blocksize='600MB', dtype='object')
print(len(list(ddf.columns)))   # Returns 207`

Then:

`print(len(columns_to_drop))

ddf.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1)
pd_df = ddf.compute()

print(len(list(ddf.columns)))`

Return 66, 207

Comment: You are missing the assignment statement (first line in my snippet).

Comment: Didn't/don't see it. Just did a search on the page but "assign" doesn't show up :/

Comment: Ah, I meant that in the snippet you provided in the comment above there should be `ddf = ddf.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1)`. Otherwise the operation is done, but not assigned to the new object (with the same name as before, `ddf`). Also, I noticed there is one typo in my snippet, will correct in a sec.

Comment: Oh - course! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `inplace=True` to `drop()`, because by default it return a copy of the original dataframe with the specified columns removed.

```
df.drop(columns_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True).compute()
```

Comment: Dask doesn't support "inplace"
`TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'`